# What's a comprehensive way to avoid multiple form submissions?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, coffeescript

In a few places in my app, users sometimes accidentally submit a form more than once. I'd like to disallow this. I'm tempted to simply put this app-wide:

```
$("form").submit ->
  TextInput.disable_submit $(this)
```

Is this the most comprehensive and safe way to go about this?

Comment: that question involves additional questions/problems about the status indicator...

Comment: the accepted answer even involves server-side code... clearly that is a much more complicated and different scenario

Comment: Look to the right. This has been asked a lot in various forms. Review them and you'll have a good idea about how to go about this. Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: i don't see anything in the right column which answers my qusetion

Comment: You've earned a downvote for lack of effort. This is a common question. It's definitely answered on this site and can easily be found with a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $('#your-submit-btn-id').prop("disabled", true);

    //Insert validation or what you need to do

)};
```

This will disable your button once it has been clicked once. You can validate and re-enable if needed using this:

```
 $('#your-submit-btn-id').prop("disabled", false);
```